# Отсортировать DataFrame по значениям столбца

Tags: python, сортировка, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, полученный из `pivot`. В столбце `ST` значения являются цифрами, но принадлежат к типам `int`, `float` и `str`:

```
                                    Club  ST
0                    SSV Jahn Regensburg  78
1                  1. FC Heidenheim 1846  71
2                   1. FC Kaiserslautern  79
3                             1. FC Köln   0
...
```

Необходимо узнать, к каким клубам принадлежат игроки с максимальным значением `ST`, т.е. отсортировать по убыванию значений столбца `ST`.

---

При выводе возникает ошибка разных типов данных, а как применить метод `max` к значениям столбца не получается:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(b.sort_values(ascending=False))
```

приводит к `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`.

Попытка фильтрации DataFrame `b2[int(b2.ST) > 90]` приводит к `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала преобразуйте столбец к числовому типу данных:

```
df["ST"] = pd.to_numeric(df["ST"], errors="coerce")
df_sorted = df.sort_values("ST", ascending=False)
```